# yaourt asking "please run yaourt as a non-privileged user"

Tags: linux, arch-linux, package-management, linux-distributions

This is a newbie question: why does yaourt in Arch Linux always warn you to "please run yaourt as a non-privileged user"? I am running the following:

```
$ sudo yaourt <package-name>
```

... to install packages from "User Repo" land.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Do you not understand the error message? Do you not understand that `sudo` runs a program as a privileged user?

Comment: I understand that `sudo` makes things happen as the root user. However, I want to install the package globally... If I run `yaourt` as a non-privileged user, will the package be installed globally?

Comment: Yes. You will be prompted to grant `yaourt` privileges when it needs them. (If that was your question, why didn't you say so?)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thanks for the insight and if you want to add that information as the answer I will give you points for it... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run it with sudo then it gives it root (super user) privileges. So you are running it as a privileged user. If you run it without sudo it should be fine.